# Why do we need special geometry for telecommunication antennas?

Tags: electromagnetism, antennas

In many youtube videos about building low power radio transmeters , I have seen a piece of regular wire or extension cord used as a antenna. But , it seems like telecommunication antennas have specific geometry (like dipole antenna , dish antenna etc).But why do we have to follow specific geometry for designing antenna?

Is it because using an extension cord as a antenna have much more power losses? If it does have , how do we calculate it?

Comment: suggest you post this on the amateur radio stack exchange- lots of friendly experts over there.

Comment: @nielsnielsen ok I have posted this question to amateur radio stack exchange.

Comment: that's good. I am learning amateur radio antenna design myself and spend a lot of time there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

at high (radio) frequencies, extension cord ("zip cord") wire has large power losses and is generally unsuitable for *transmitting* antennas.

telecomm antennas are built so as to produce as much electromagnetic radiation as possible, and point it in the desired direction. They have a wide variety of shapes to do this.

The amateur radio stack exchange is a better place to post this question. Lots of friendly experts over there who are happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

The geometry of antenna changes its radiation pattern. This pattern is important for reception also (reciprocity theorem). One have to adapt this pattern in order to obtain a certain directivity of antenna. Also the geometry defines which polarization of electromagnetic wave will be  emitted and, in case of reception, what polarization the antenna will "absorb" better.